# Git: How to discard changes that you pulled ahead of you, and let your local changes become the new branch head

Tags: git, bitbucket, sourcetree

Someone I work with committed corrupted files to the master git branch. My local version of master branch is ahead with changes to keep, while his changes should go in the trash. I am trying to resolve this in Source Tree, I must pull his crap before I can push my stuff, and then when I try to discard them I get bunch of errors like "error: path '...' is unmerged" and "error: pathspec '...' did not match any file(s) known to git."

Answer (score 0):

From you comment, it seems you push directly to remote master. I'd suggest you create a new branch, revert that person's corrupted code; then merge your current work onto that branch, you can then push that branch.

Check the accepted answer here if it helps: [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)